# Repeat tag caching?

Tags: xpages

This is driving me crazy today, so I need to figure out if I'm doing something wrong or fundamentally misunderstanding how this works.

I have a custom control with two tags computing from the same backing bean like so:

```
    <xp:text
        id="test1"
        value="#{claimsFiledReport.rows}">
    </xp:text>
    <xp:repeat
        id="repeatDataRows"
        value="#{claimsFiledReport.rows}"
        var="row"
        repeatControls="true">

        <... stuff here ...>

    </xp:repeat>
```

The backing bean is supplying this information like so:

```
public List<List<String>> getRows() {
    System.out.println("running getRows()");
    List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    for (ReportLine line : getLines().values()) {
        List<String> lineData = new ArrayList<String>();
        lineData.addAll(line.getValueStringList());
        list.add(lineData);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Now for the part I don't understand:

When I first load up the page, the console prints `running getRows()` twice, and in the browser everything is blank because the report hasn't run yet. I then have a button which runs the report and refreshes the table that contains both of these controls. When that happens, `running getRows()` is only printed once, and only the text control shows data. The repeat control remains blank. So the only thing that makes any sense is that the repeat control is caching the result of getRows(), but that isn't the behavior I expect.

Also, if I put `runReport()` as the first line of `getRows()`, then my table is populated with default data and if I try to change my filter and rerun the report, the table is unchanged, while the computed text updates.

So my question is really whether I'm misunderstanding how a repeat control interfaces with a backing bean and if so how to work around that, or if I have some sort of implementation issue that I just can't find.

Comment: The plot thickens: I added a pager control for the repeat control and that seems to have resolved the issue. In order to do this, I removed `repeatControls=true` and set `rows=30`. Those had been set that way so that the entire report would appear on a single page, so this isn't the ideal solution. I'll investigate further...

Comment: What's the scope of your bean? BTW you can compute the pager controls completely by setting the "alwaysComputeLast" property of the repeat to "true"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`repeatControls="true"` means "get the contents for the repeat on page load and never after that". So the contents of the repeat are what they were the first time the page was loaded. In your first example, `runReport()` has no data, so the repeat is blank. In the second example, `runReport()` is set, so the report is blank. But repeatControls being true means it's created a set of controls for each element of `runReport()` and stored those.

The computed field control though will display the up-to-date information, because it's value is dynamic.

Think of it like setting `loaded="#{viewScope.myVal==true}"` on a panel and trying to use partial refresh to show that panel by setting `viewScope.myVal=true`. Similarly, you get what you had at page load.

Basically, if you want to change the content in a repeat (that includes using a pager), you can't use `repeatControl="true"`.

The difference between setting repeatControls and using a page load binding (${...}) on the value of the repeat is that by doing a page load binding, you can still use a pager. The use case is if you want to build the contents of the repeat control in the component tree, but then remove the repeat from the component tree.

getRows() will run twice on page load, because it's called from two components, that's fine.

Comment: Thanks, Paul. I had been trying to just get the entire report to appear on a single page without having to worry about how many lines there are and by following the help text for rows, it seemed I needed to set `repeatControls="false"` in order to get that to work. And that sent me way down the wrong path there. Thanks again.

Comment: One option may be to bind the rows property to another property in your bean. Then set that also in the runReport() method.